# To clear contents and to resize certain Rows and Columns

Tags: vba, excel

The code works fine when I dont use the first command to clear contents.After clearing the contents I got a "Paste Special Error" when I used the command to consolidate certain rows and columns.I need to reduce the size of certain rows and columns(wrap text) as it is taking a lot of space

```
Private Sub Btn_clear_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells.ClearContents
End Sub
```

(I am to able to clear the cell contents using this)

```
Sub Credit_Risk_Components()

Const FOLDER As String = "C:\SBI_Files\"
Const cStrWSName As String = "Credit Risk Components"
'(I got a paste value error here)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim i As Integer
Dim fileName As String


' Cleaning Credit Indicators (Both amount and percentage) '
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C8:C16").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C20").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C23:C25").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C40:C47").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C52:C59").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C66").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C68").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C71:C73").ClearContents

'Cleaning the Annexure Section'
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H6:K200").UnMerge
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H6:K200").ClearFormats
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H6:K200").ClearContents
(I want to resize certain rows and columns,as the rows and columns are taking a lot of space which isn't required)
'Building the Annexure Section'
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H4").Value = "Annexure I"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H4:K4").Merge
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H4:K4").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("H4:K4").Font.Bold = True

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(5, 2).Copy Cells(5, 9)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(5, 3).Copy Cells(5, 10)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(5, 4).Copy Cells(5, 11)


fileName = Dir(FOLDER, vbDirectory)
Do While Len(fileName) > 0

    If Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "xls" Then
        i = i + 1
        Dim currentWkbk As Excel.Workbook
        Set currentWkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C10").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C10").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C10").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C11").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C11").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C11").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C13").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C13").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C13").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C14").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C14").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C14").Value


        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C16").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C16").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C16").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C20").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C20").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C20").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C23").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C23").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C23").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C24").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C24").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C24").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C25").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C25").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C25").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C40").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C40").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C40").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C41").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C41").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C41").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C42").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C42").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C42").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C43").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C43").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C43").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C44").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C44").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C44").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C45").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C45").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C45").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C46").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C46").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C46").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C47").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C47").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C47").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C52").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C52").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C52").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C53").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C53").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C53").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C54").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C54").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C54").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C56").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C56").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C56").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C57").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C57").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C57").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C58").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C58").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C58").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C59").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C59").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C59").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C66").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C66").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C66").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C68").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C68").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C68").Value

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C71").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C71").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C71").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C72").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C72").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C72").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C73").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("C73").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("C73").Value



        'Adding the Prudential/ Industrial Exposures to the annexure'

        rowNum = Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row


        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(rowNum + 1, 8).Value = Left(currentWkbk.Name, Len(currentWkbk.Name) - 4)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(rowNum + 1, 8).Font.Bold = True
        currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("B29:D38").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(Cells(rowNum + 2, 9), Cells(rowNum + 11, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(Cells(rowNum + 2, 9), Cells(rowNum + 11, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        currentWkbk.Sheets(cStrWSName).Range("B76:D79").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(Cells(rowNum + 12, 9), Cells(rowNum + 15, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(Cells(rowNum + 12, 9), Cells(rowNum + 15, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats



        currentWkbk.Close
    End If
    fileName = Dir
    Loop
ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out error handler and check what line fails.

FYI, .xlsx does not allow any code (unless your code is run outside).

Based on your error message there is something wrong with PasteSpecial method you use in the end. Try copying the same manually.

BTW, your code should be refactored.